# Removing double spaces in the middle of an output

Tags: vba, excel

So I am using an API with some VBA in excel and the output I get from the program puts a double space in the middle of the numbers like 123456  7891011.  My current solution is this,

```
With ws.Range("J2:J98")
    .Formula = "=LEFT(I2,6)"
End With
With ws.Range("K2:K98")
    .Formula = "=RIGHT(I2,7)"
End With
With ws.Range("L2:L98")
    .Formula = "=CONCATENATE(J2,K2)"
    .Value = .Value
    .NumberFormat = "0"
End With
```

With J and K hidden.

My question is:  Is there a way to do this without using Cells to hold the formulas?

Here is the code I use to pull what I want to modify

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(k, 9) = Trim(autECLSession.autECLPS.GetText(4, 24, 15))
```

and the solution Is

```
With ws.Range("L2:L98")
    .Formula = "=Substitute(I2,""  "", """")"
    .Value = .Value
    .NumberFormat = "0"
End With
```

An amendment to my question is do I even need the output to hit a Cell or can i run the substitute before it does?

Comment: just change `.Formula = "=CONCATENATE(J2,K2)"` to `.Formula = "=CONCATENATE(LEFT(I2,6),RIGHT(I2,7))"` or simply use `.Formula = "=SUBSTITUTE(I2,"" "","""")"`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is to use substitute instead of taking the left and the right and concatenating them:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(I2;"  ";"")
```

This would decrease the number of hideen colums needed.

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but you could replace the original contents with a loop over the selected/target area. Then no formulas would be needed and the original range would be replaced with the new values.

Comment: So just used the substitute formula that simoco gave me which works but I guess I dont understand your 2nd part of your answer.  Would I be able to save the output as a Long and then run the substitute over it?

Comment: Ron below implemented my suggestion. You could write a macro like this : http://pastebin.com/VKwJ58yH

Answer (score 0):

```
Activecell = Range("J2")
for x=1 to 97
   if instr(1, activecell, "  ") > 0 then   ' test do see if a double space is present in the activecell
      activecell = replace(activecell, "  ", "")   ' if so, remove it
   else
   end if
next x
```